# C# Assembly reference / class library user context - calling from SSRS

Tags: c#, reporting-services, class-library, ssrs-2012

I have a C# class library which I am using as an assembly reference from SSRS.

I am trying to find out what user the .dll will run under as I need to access a file in the %USERPROFILE%. When I do the following it crashes:

```
string loc = @"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\app";
loc= Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(loc);
```

It's the ExpandEnvironmentVariables that causes the crash.

So I took a step back and tried to just find out the current user using:

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME")
```

and

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

by writing them out to a text file:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\\Users\\Public\\pass.txt", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

but the text file never appears as it crashes trying to get the username. I do have permission to write to the text file.

Tried from both the report viewer within SSRS as well as deployed to localhost - neither can get me the name.

Ultimately, I want the user context to be the IIS user (from the ASP.NET app) that is calling the SSRS report (which will be a domain account) - is this going to be possible?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You say it crashes but what exceptions is it throwing?

Comment: Don't get an exceptions unfortunately :(....the report just says it couldn't process. I am guessing it crashes as I output other 'pass.txt' files to step through the code and only the first one is writing (which is produced on the first line)

Comment: Do you have try/catch blocks around the offending statements?

Comment: Argh silly me! I had the try catch but the exception was written to a file I didn't assert permissions to! Hence it wasn't showing. Turns out the error was: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, and putting <trust level="Full"/> in web.config solved it. Thanks for your help!